# How can I verify certain split-values in certain values from dict in python?

Tags: python, split

I`m trying to verify see if certain split values from a list are in certain values from dict in python.

For example,

```
user_input = ".."
morse_code = {"A": ".-", "N": "-.", "B": "-...", "O": "---", "C": "-.-.", "P": ".--.", "D": "-..", "Q": "--.-", "E": ".", "R": ".-.", "F": "..-.", "S": "...", "G": "--.", "T": "-", "H": "....", "U": "..-", "I": "..", "V": "...-", "K": "-.-", "X": "-..-", "J": ".---", "W": ".--", "L": ".-..", "Y": "-.--", "M": "--", "Z": "--.."}
>>> user_input in morse_code.values()
True
>>> user_input.split() in morse_code.values()
False
```

I thought `user_input == user_input.split()` but it`s not. Why is that??

Comment: `str.split()` returns a list, *always*, even if it only contains a single element. None of you values in the dictionary are lists.

Comment: Why did you want to split?

Comment: Did you `print(user_input.split())`? that's all it takes to see that it's different from `user_input`

Answer (score 2):

It's beacuse `split` method retuns a list of elements.

```
>>> user_input.split()
['..']
>>> user_input
'..'
```

You ahve no list in your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all`, `any`, or list compressions:

```
if all([i for i in user_input.split() if i in morse_code.values()]) # True if all the split items are in the values

if any([i for i in user_input.split() if i in morse_code.values()]) # True if any of the split items are in the values

valids = [i for i in user_input.split() if i in morse_code.values()]
```

The last will return, in `valids` a list of all of the items in the split that match the values.  You could almost certainly speed up the processing by constructing a set of the values first, i.e.:

```
codes = morse.values()
valids = [i for i in user_input.split() if i in codes]
```

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?